# Why doesn't getUpdatedRecords() return a list of modified records in an Ext JS Property Grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Please try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pL5Df/).

Open a console, run the jsFiddle, alter a property value, and click "Write state to console".

Why does the store still report zero updated records?  It knows the new value for the property.

This is the Ext JS 4.2 code in JsFiddle:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    


Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.grid.PropertyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    requires: [
        'Ext.button.Button',
        'Ext.grid.property.*',
        'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
        'Ext.layout.container.HBox'
    ],
    xtype: 'property-grid',


    height: 275,
    width: 300,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    initComponent: function(){
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                margin: '0 0 10 0',
                defaultType: 'button',
                items: [{
                    text: 'Write state to console',
                    margin: '0 0 0 10',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onWriteStateClick
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'propertygrid',
                source: {
                    weight: 0.01,
                    distance: 1
                }
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    },

    onWriteStateClick: function(){
        var grid = this.down('propertygrid');

        var store = grid.getStore();
        console.log("Number of new records: " + store.getNewRecords().length);
        console.log("Number of updated records: " + store.getUpdatedRecords().length);
        console.log("Number of deleted records: " + store.getRemovedRecords().length);

        store.each(function (rec) {
            console.log("store says --> key: " + rec.get("name") + ", value: " + rec.get("value"));
        });

        //var source = grid.getSource();
        //Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
        //    console.log("source says --> key: " + key + ", value: " + source[key]);
        //});
    },


});


Ext.create('KitchenSink.view.grid.PropertyGrid', { renderTo: Ext.getBody() });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `property-grid` makes use of memory proxy, which does not keep track of modified records.

The long answer is that the new/deleted/updated trace is only implemented for server proxies, or more specifically, to fields that are persisted to the server. A client proxy, like memory proxy, does not need this as it never syncs to the server.

The deeper explanation to this is in this code, from the [model's `set` method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-set):

```
if (field && field.persist) {
    if (modified.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        if (me.isEqual(modified[name], value)) {
            // The original value in me.modified equals the new value, so
            // the field is no longer modified:
            delete modified[name];

            // We might have removed the last modified field, so check to
            // see if there are any modified fields remaining and correct
            // me.dirty:
            me.dirty = false;
            for (key in modified) {
                if (modified.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    me.dirty = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        me.dirty = true;
        modified[name] = currentValue;
    }
}
```

You can see that if the field is not persisted (like it would never be with client proxy) it doesn't get the `dirty` flag, and without it the store won't gather that the record has changed.

Even if you would define persist for your model fields, the sync mechanism requires an id field.

So to conclude - you don't get this with client proxies, like the one used behind the scenes in your example.